# App Actions: Fulfillment intent parameter missing entity set reference

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-play-console, google-assistant, app-actions

Im implementing a Google Assistant integration logic for my app for the first time. The implementation is showing a widget inside GA with some in-app data. When tested locally using the Android Studio [plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/test-tool) everything works fine.

This is my shortcuts.xml file:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <capability
        android:name="actions.intent.GET_THING">
        <app-widget
            android:identifier="GET_THING_1"
            android:targetClass="com.myapp.widget.MyWidget">
            <parameter
                android:name="thing.name"
                android:key="shortcutId"
                android:required="true"
                app:shortcutMatchRequired="true" />
            <extra android:name="hasTts" android:value="true"/>
        </app-widget>
        <intent android:identifier="GET_THING_FALLBACK"
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="com.myapp.widget.MyWidget" />
    </capability>

</shortcuts>
```

But when submitting the app to the Play Store its rejected with the following response:

> After review, your app has been rejected due to issues with your action.xml file. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> **Issues in Action.xml file by APK version**
>
> Fulfillment intent parameter **thing.name** is missing an entity set reference for a parameter with the same name.

I dont really understand this comment. It seems to be referring to the deprecated [actions.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/legacy/action-schema) framework, where `<entity-set>` elements are being used, but i dont use it at all.

My best guess is the fact that im using `app:shortcutMatchRequired="true"` in my capability but my shortcuts are created dynamically, but that is completely far fetched.

Help is very much needed here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error message you got does not really reflect the error: a missing fallback intent. You can try and add a Fallback Intent with no parameters, such as seen on this [example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/shortcuts.xml).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @Elaine. I mistakenly left out the fallback intent from my sample here, but it was part of the submitted shortcuts.xml file. I edited my question to reflect that. So this is not reason for the store rejection.

Comment: I see :/ the last thing I'd try is adding the thing.name parameter in the fallback intent aswell. As if it was a ["classic" App Actions integration](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/get-started#implement_the_get_thing_built-in_intent).